# Press F12 to open the inspect window on selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a very specific need using selenium and I do not want to use pyautogui to do so. I need, at some moment of the program's execution, to open the inspect window( Developer's Window). I tried directly sending keys to the body element and using action chains and did not suceded in any. There is a way to automatically open the developer's window setting the options of the webdriver that worked, but there is no option to activate it at a certain point of the execution, making it always opened.
I would like to know if there is a way to send those key inputs without resorting to manual intervention.

I tried what I mentioned before, it did not work as intended

Comment: what is your exactly purpose to open Inspect?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas, for some reason the element is visible on the screen, I have its xpath, it's an input element, I send the file to it but if I do not open the inspect window it doesn't go through the delivery of the file. I don't understand why it's happening, it's not inside an iframe, it's inside a bunch of divs

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+I or Ctrl+Shift+J already?